# Output only numbers from print string as input

Tags: python, image, input, output, blob

I am trying to pass the x,y coordinates of a blob obtained from an image as the integers for the next part of my code.
From there I hope to use these coordinates to obtain the rgb coordinates from a comparison image(at the same xy).
New to code, any help is appreciated.

```
img = Image('/home/pi/Desktop/folder1/img1.jpg')
img.findBlobs()
print img.findBlobs()
```

Prints = Example: [SimpleCV.Features.Blob.Blob object at (120, 391) with area 19]

How can I pass the tuple (120, 391) above as x, y in the next part of code

```
pixcol = Image('/home/pi/Desktop/folder4/colourSegments.jpg') ###Image with areas of different colours
colrgb =  pixcol[ x, y ]
```

Returns RGB of (X,Y)  ## Example: (63.0, 71.0, 204.0)

Comment: Your question is actually "How do I get the x and y pixel coordinates of a SimpleCV.Features.Blob.Blob object?"  An obvious first step would be to check the documentation for that type of object and see what methods it has.

Comment: I have the x y coordinates, I need to input them into the next part of my code, in order to return the RGB values of the specific x y coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Paul Cornelius said, all you need is to check documentation about Blob object.

```
img = Image('/home/pi/Desktop/folder1/img1.jpg')
blobs = img.findBlobs()
#btw, it is an array of blobs, which one do you need to check?
first_blob = blobs[0] if blobs else None
if first_blob
    pixcol = Image('/home/pi/Desktop/folder4/colourSegments.jpg') ###Image with areas of different colours
    colrgb =  pixcol[first_blob.x, first_blob.y]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect, I will be working with only one blob per image.